# how to get a count of an entry in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
________________________________
|oc_ct_forum_reply              |
--------------------------------|
| forum_reply_id | forum_post_id|
|-------------------------------|
|  21            |  25          |
|  22            |  25          |
|  25            |  25          |
|  28            |  25          |
---------------------------------
```

I have a table named `oc_ct_forum_reply` trying to find the first `forum_reply_id` with the following sql query:

```
  SELECT forum_reply_id
    FROM oc_ct_forum_reply
   WHERE forum_post_id = 25
ORDER BY reply_added
   LIMIT 1
       ;
```

i use another one to get the total number of replies for the forum_post_id:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM oc_ct_forum_reply
   WHERE forum_post_id = 25
       ;
```

I need an sql query that gives me the position of a given `forum_reply_id` among the sorted `forum_reply_id`s belonging to a given `forum_post_id`. let's say i supply `forum_post_id` 25 and `forum_reply_id` 25, i want the query to return `3` as its the 3rd entry, or say i supply a `forum_post_id` of 25 and a `forum_reply_id` of 28, i wish to get the value `4` as its the fourth entry. I've tried all sorts of combinations using the two queries above.

Comment: `count()` is an "inventory" function. it tells you how many of some particular thing you have. it does not tell you WHERE in the inventory the result was found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT 
  t1.forum_reply_id,
  count(t2.forum_reply_id) as reply_number
FROM
  oc_ct_forum_reply t1
  JOIN oc_ct_forum_reply t2 ON ( t1.forum_reply_id >= t2.forum_reply_id AND t1.forum_post_id = t2.forum_post_id )
WHERE
  t1.forum_reply_id = 25
  AND t1.forum_post_id = 25
GROUP BY
  t1.forum_reply_id
```

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5df2f/6)**

### **Working**

1. `oc_ct_forum_reply t1` gets the row having `forum_reply_id = 25 AND t1.forum_post_id = 25`
2. Then, I do a `SELF JOIN` to get the **current reply_id's number**
   (by getting all the rows that have `forum_reply_id` less or equal to the current `t1.forum_reply_id` and which have the same `forum_post_id` of `t1`
    and then grouping them

The above actions fetch `3 rows`, as

```
t1.forum_reply_id , t2.forum_reply_id 
-----------------------------
 25               , 21                
 25               , 22                
 25               , 25
```

Finally, I just `GROUP BY t1.forum_reply_id` and use the [**COUNT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) aggregate function to display the `total rows` present for the requested `forum_reply_id` ( 25 )

Comment: Whats table1 and table2 ?? There is only one table called oc_ct_forum_reply and the fields forum_reply_id and forum_post_id ??

Comment: Looking good , I see how to pass the forum_reply_id to search for but where dio i enter the forum_post_id too ?

Comment: append it in the outer-most clause, as `WHERE
  t1.forum_reply_id = 25 AND t1.forum_reply_id = 25`

Comment: you put in forum_reply_id twice i need to get the value from searching forum_reply_id & forum_post_id

Comment: sorry a type, it should be `WHERE t1.forum_reply_id = 25 AND t1.forum_post_id = 25`, I have updated the answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

an alternative:

```
SELECT rownum FROM
(
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, oc_ct_forum_reply.* 
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, oc_ct_forum_reply
) result_table
WHERE FORUM_REPLY_ID = 25;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5df2f/29